# TypeError: reaction.users is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord

i know little English, sorry :).

I made a DiscordJS V12 code with DiscordJS V11 and changed it a bit, but error receiving. Can you help?

Code;
`const author = reaction.users.last()`

Error:
`(node:1562) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: reaction.users is not a function`

i use discord.js v12

I'll make a ticket system. I'm getting an error...

reaction.users.last I think version 11.

i need version 12 reaction.users.last but i couldnt find it..

Comment: Please provide the necessary code. Which event are you in? What is `reaction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is fixed...
`reaction.users.cache.last` is true

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a typo in the function name? Maybe the object you are calling the method on does not have this function? For example, JavaScript Objects have no map function, but the JavaScript Array object does.

IE:
array.map() //this would work
object.map() //this would not work

I'd figure out what reaction.users or reaction is to start..

Comment: My code; [link](http://egecode.glitch.me/vlV90OD2RK)

Comment: awesome that you fixed the bug! If my answer helped provide any clarity I would appreciate an upvote! Thanks :)